# LDAP user filter error at cn=%v

Tags: ldap, gitlab

In LDAP settings of my Gitlab, I used

`user_filter : '(memberof=CN=%v,OU=groupname,DC=company,DC=local)`

But it gives me an error:

> malformed formed format string - %v

What should be the format that I can give the filter for a username in `CN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [GitLAb LDAP man page](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/7a6e88263c922f44e498cd75edd3e4bb1f7469fc/doc/administration/auth/ldap.md), the syntax should follow [RFC 4515](https://tools.ietf.org/search/rfc4515) only:

```
  # Filter LDAP users
  #
  #   Format: RFC 4515 https://tools.ietf.org/search/rfc4515
  #   Ex. (employeeType=developer)
  #
  #   Note: GitLab does not support omniauth-ldap's custom filter syntax.
  #
  #   Example for getting only specific users:
  #   '(&(objectclass=user)(|(samaccountname=momo)(samaccountname=toto)))'
  #
  user_filter: ''
```

In your case, the CN should be the name of a group, not a placeholder like `%v`.
See as an example [gitlab-ce issue 34150](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/34150)

You can test it with:

> Try running this set of queries through the Rails console without the filter set, and then with the filter set.
>   Start the Rails console with `sudo gitlab-rails console`.

```
adapter = Gitlab::LDAP::Adapter.new('ldapmain')
person = Gitlab::LDAP::Person.find_by_uid('<username>', adapter)
person.memberof
```

Comment: NameError: Uninitialized constant LDAP::Adapter

Comment: I saw a MSDN page and used `v` as universal username. I was wrong

Comment: Ok, what did you use in the end?